# Magnolia 5.5.5 Custom content editor with nested blocks

Tags: ckeditor, editor, magnolia

I am using Magnolia 5.5.5 with a custom stories app and I want the possibility to have text and image in one block. So that i can write a text and then decide whether the image is below/above/left/right and the text will float around it.

The following is tested and will NOT work:

```
class: info.magnolia.editor.block.stock.FieldSetBlockDefinition
templateId: stories-app:blocks/textImage
icon: text-block
label: textImage
fields:
  text:
    blockClass: info.magnolia.editor.block.stock.RichTextBlock
  image:
    class: info.magnolia.editor.app.field.ExpandingLinkFieldDefinition
    buttonSelectNewLabel: browse
    buttonSelectOtherLabel: browse
    ....
```

Something like this would be great. Otherwise I would have to do positioning in the `for block in blocks` loop and with css. While I think its feasable what do you think about nested blocks? How would you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you’re going around it wrong. Content editor is presentation agnostic and you want to break it.
Instead you should solve it only in template rendering the article where you discover text blocks and image block and position image and let text flow around it accordingly.